# A countale partially ordered set that has an uncountable number of maximal chains

Tags: set-theory, examples-counterexamples

I'm looking for a countable set S with a partial order < that has an uncoubtable number of  maximal chains. I had many ideas but non of then is correct (for example- S= natural numbers, "<" is division- a < b iff a|b. But I think that in this case the numebr of maximal chains is countable).

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take $S$ to be the set of all finite binary strings, and say $a\lt b$ iff $a$ is a prefix of $b$. Then every infinite binary string defines a maximal chain in $S$, and there are uncountably many infinite binary strings.

You can picture this same example as an infinite binary tree, which has countably many nodes but uncountably many branches; here $a\lt b$ iff $a$ is an ancestor of $b$.

Comment: GREAT! thanks a lot

Comment: @user18217: You're welcome!