# Where the set of maximal chains is $2^{\aleph_0}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Exam preparation question:

How to find a partial ordered set $(P,\leq)$, such that $|P|=\aleph_0 $  and the set of all maximal chain in $(P,\leq)$ is $2^{\aleph_0}$?

Thank you!

Comment: I am fairly certain that you asked this before and that Brian had answered that.

Comment: @Asaf: [This one](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/246812/finding-maximal-chain-of-cardinality-aleph)?

Comment: @Brian: Yes, I just found it myself as well!

Comment: oops, my apologies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Somewhat less usual than Brian's answer:

All the (nontrivial) open intervals in $\mathbb R$ with rational endpoints, ordered by reverse inclusion.

This poset is countable, and every maximal chain corresponds to a decreasing sequence of open sets whose intersection must be at most a single real number. There are at most $2^{\aleph_0}$ chains, and for every real number we can generate such maximal chain. Therefore there are exactly $2^{\aleph_0}$ maximal chains.

Comment: For each real number you can generate quite a few maximal chains. You’re still okay, of course, since there are only $2^\omega$ sets of intervals.

Comment: Yes, I didn't say that each real generates a unique chain... But it's a good as any argument for showing there are exactly $\frak c$ maximal chains.

Comment: There are maximal chains with empty intersection, such as $\{(0,q)\mid q>0\}$. (This does not upset the argument here, of course, for the same reason as Brian's point doesn't).

Comment: @Henning: Thanks, I corrected this.

Comment: AsafKaragila, Brian M.Scott: thank you very much for all the help in last three months... :)

Comment: @17SI.34SA: Sure. I hope the exam wasn't too hard. Maybe I'll see you in my class in three weeks, too.

Answer (score 2):

HINT: The complete binary tree of height $\omega$ has $\omega$ (or $\aleph_0$, if you prefer) vertices and $2^\omega$ branches.