# Find chain and antichain equivalent to R

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Given partial order $(P(\mathbb{N}), \subset)$. I have to find chain and antichain in this partiar order equipotent to $\mathbb{R}$. Actually, I don't have any idea how to begin :) Any hints?

Comment: $|\mathbb Q|=|\mathbb N|$.

Comment: Many duplicates. Chains: [one](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/246812/622), [two](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/298323/622), [three](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/244893/622). Antichains: [four](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/162387/622), [five](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/278837/622)... there are probably more of each type.

Answer (score 3):

HINT: $|\Bbb Q|=|\Bbb N|$, so you can replace $\Bbb N$ by $\Bbb Q$. Then for the first part think about [Dedekind cuts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind_cut) — specifically, their downward halves, say. For the second part, take a look at [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/278837/sets-of-natural-numbers) and the answer given there (or the answers given at the linked earlier question).

Comment: You beat me for that one link, but I've beaten you for four others! :-)